# Ribbon Enable rule is called twice

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I added an Enable rule with a custom javascript rule to hide a ribbon button whenever required. It works fine, but it's called twice.

I added a `console.trace()` call to see what's the stack trace, and saw the following - You can see that the second call is doing a refresh.

I did another few tests, and eventually figured out that what causes the second call is a call to any of the `Xrm` utility functions (so that if `myButtonFunc` execution *doesn't* contains this kind of call, it won't be fired twice).

First call:

```
(anonymous function)
evaluate
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame
myRibbonObj.myButtonFunc            <-- my ribbon's button function 
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$Bz_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$FU_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$By_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$FQ_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$Eb_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.canHandleCommand
Mscrm.CommandData.isControlEnabled
Mscrm.CommandBarData.isControlEnabled
Mscrm.CommandBar.$7b
Mscrm.CommandBar.evaluateCommands
Mscrm.CommandBarBuilder.$BY_0
Mscrm.CommandBarBuilder.$BS_0
Mscrm.CommandBarBuilder.$EF_0
Mscrm.CommandBarBuilder.$Hg_0
Mscrm.CommandBarBuilder.buildCommandBar
Mscrm.RibbonManager.$Cg_3
$v_0
```

Second call:

```
(anonymous function)
evaluate
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame
myRibbonObj.myButtonFunc            <-- my ribbon's button function 
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$Bz_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$FU_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$By_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$FQ_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.$Eb_1
Mscrm.CommandHandler.canHandleCommand
Mscrm.CommandData.isControlEnabled
Mscrm.CommandBarData.isControlEnabled
Mscrm.CommandBar.$7b
Mscrm.CommandBar.evaluateCommands
Mscrm.CommandBar.refreshCommandBar
Mscrm.CommandBar.refresh
Mscrm.CommandBarBuilder.refreshCommandBar <-- note this refresh
Mscrm.RibbonManager.$Hl_3
Mscrm.RibbonManager.$Hm_3
Mscrm.RibbonManager.$Hr_3
(anonymous function)
```

Obviously, I want the function to execute once. I tried what's suggested [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kFDyhCgAXi8J:https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/261110%20&cd=1&hl=iw&ct=clnk&gl=il):

```
var triggered = false;

function RibbonButtonClick() {
    CallMyFunction();
}

function CallMyFunction() {
  if (triggered == false) {
     triggered = true;
     // ... your function body follows ...
     return false; // hide the button
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work - apparently, the button is displayed/hidden based on the return value of the *second* call!

So I tried the opposite - made the required logic to run on the second call:

```
function CallMyFunction() {
  if (triggered == false) {
    triggered = true;
    var dummy = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
  } else {
    // ... your function body follows ...
    return false; // hide the button
  }
}
```

but this is really hacky - it needs to have a dummy call to an `Xrm` function to enable the second call.

My question: Can this be resolved otherwise?

Comment: Stackoverflow is quite lonely for Dynamics CRM developers =(